# How to downgrade Odoo 9 EE to CE?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-9, downgrade, dbmigrate

I've Odoo 9 EE installed, and I wanna downgrade it to CE, so how can I do that ?

I found this tutorial but I didn't get it working :

https://www.quora.com/Can-we-install-enterprise-modules-in-Odoo-community-while-hosting-on-premise

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. Uninstall `web_enterprise` module.
2. Remove enterprise addons path from config file if any.
3. Refresh the page ( maybe you have to clear the cache or login incognito window).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I'll try it, but what about the DB ?

Comment: Leave it as it is, Odoo will take care of it.

Comment: So, I didn't find web_entreprise, it's installed on windows !

Comment: Could you search in the installed module list, Go to `Apps`, set filter ` Installed`.

Comment: do you mean website_entreprise ?

Comment: In 11.0, i do have both `web_enterprise` and `website_enterprise`.

Comment: In my case i installed on `web_enterprise`.